# MySQL Disparador para completar una segunda tabla

Tags: mysql, autocompletar

tengo dos tablas **Funcionarios** (id_funcionario, RUT, Nombre, etc) y **Ejecutantes** (id_ejecutante, id_funcionario), lo que deseo hacer es que al momento de ingresar un dato en la tabla funcionario, automaticamente se traspase la id_funcionario a la tabla ejecutantes. Estaba tratando de hacerlo con un disparador, aplicando el siguiente código:

`` INSERT INTO `ejecutantes` (`ejecutante_id`, `funcionario_id`) VALUES (NULL, funcionario_id) ``

Hasta ahí me da error en el id_funcionario, ya que tengo relacionadas las tablas, el PK id_funcionario de la tabla **Funcionario** con el FK id_funcionario de la tabla **ejecutantes**

Agradezco de antemano cualquier orientación o sugerencia, saludos!

Comment: Has utilizado `funcionario_id` en vez `id_funcionario`; y `ejecutante_id` en vez de `id_ejecutante`, ¿necesitas ayuda con el disparador?

Comment: Gracias Estimado!, quedó Ok

Answer (score 0):

agregué un "new" en mi consulta SQL

```
INSERT INTO `ejecutantes` (`ejecutante_id`, `funcionario_id`) VALUES (NULL, **new**.funcionario_id)
```